# scala overriding None

Tags: scala

My first Scala program and I am stuck.

So basically i am trying to override the potential None value of "last" to a 0l in the declaration of past.

```
import java.util.Date;

object TimeUtil {
    var timerM = Map( "" -> new Date().getTime() );

    def timeit(seq:String, comment:String) {
        val last = timerM.get(seq) 
        val cur = new Date().getTime()
        timerM += seq -> cur;
        println( timerM )
        if( last == None ) return;

        val past = ( last == None ) ? 0l : last  ;
        Console.println("Time:" + seq + comment + ":" + (cur - past)/1000  )
    }

    def main(args : Array[String]) {
        timeit("setup ", "mmm")
        timeit("setup ", "done")
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to take out the line `if( last == None ) return;`?  As written, `last` will never be `None` when initializing `past`. That said, the idiomatic way to write that initializer would be `val past = last getOrElse 01`.

Comment: ah well, there was this compiler error and I thought maybe its not smart enough to infer that the logic prevents it from being null.

Comment: You should always include any error information in your question, if applicable (which it transparently is, in this case)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should probably try and distil the problem a little more, but **certainly** include your actual error!

However, there is **no ternary operator (`? :`) in Scala** so instead you can use:

```
if (pred) a else b //instead of pred ? a : b
```

This is because (*almost* - see Kevin's comments below) everything in scala is an *expression* with a return type. This is not true in Java where some things are statements (with no type). With scala, it's always better to use composition, rather than forking (i.e. the `if (expr) return;` in your example). So I would re-write this as:

```
val last = timerM.get(seq)
val cur = System.currentTimeMillis
timerM += (seq -> cur)
println(timerM)
last.foreach{l => println("Time: " + seq + comment + ":" + (l - past)/1000 ) }
```

Note that the ternary operation in your example is extraneous anyway, because `last` cannot be None at that point (you have just returned if it were). My advice is to use explicit types for a short while, as you get used to Scala. So the above would then be:

```
val last: Option[Long] = timerM.get(seq)
val cur: Long = System.currentTimeMillis
timerM += (seq -> cur)
println(timerM)
last.foreach{l : Long => println("Time: " + seq + comment + ":" + (l - past)/1000 ) }
```

*(It seems in your comment that you might be trying to assign a `Long` value to `last`, which would be an error of course, because `last` is of type `Option[Long]`, not `Long`)*

Comment: thanks. suppose this works too Console.println("Hi:"+ ( cur - last.getOrElse(0L) )

Comment: I, too, made this mistake.  Not everything in Scala is an expression, variable, class and method definitions are statements, as are import statements and (I think) assignment.  When the compiler encounters a code block that terminates with a statement, it'll insert the expression `()` at the end if you try to evaluate that block - thus giving the *appearance* that everything is an expression.

Comment: You're wrong about assignment; it is an expression of type `Unit` but the point still stands. I should have been clearer

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't 100% sure on that one myself.

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple of "code smells" in there, which suggest that a better, shinier design is probably just around the corner:

- You're using a mutable variable, var instead of val
- timeit works exclusively by side effects, it modifies state outside of the function and successive calls with the same input can have different results.
- `seq` is slightly risky as a variable name, it's far too close to the (very common & popular) `Seq` type from the standard library.

So going back to first principles, how else might the same results be achieved in a more "idiomatic" style?  Starting with the original design (as I understand it):

- the first call to `timeit(seq,comment)` just notes the current time
- subsequent calls with the same value of `seq` println the time elapsed since the previous call

Basically, you just want to time how long a block of code takes to run.  If there was a way to pass a "block of code" to a function, then maybe, just maybe...  Fortunately, scala can do this, just use a by-name param:

```
def timeit(block: => Unit) : Long = {
  val start = System.currentTimeMillis
  block
  System.currentTimeMillis - start
}
```

Just check out that `block` parameter, it looks a bit like a function with no arguments, that's how by-name params are written.  The last expression of the function `System.currentTimeMillis - start` is used as the return value.

By wrapping the parameter list in {} braces instead of () parentheses, you can make it look like a built-in control structure, and use it like this:

```
val duration = timeit {
  do stuff here
  more stuff
  do other stuff
}

println("setup time:" + duration + "ms")
```

Alternatively, you can push the println behaviour back into the timeit function, but that makes life harder if you later want to reuse it for timing something without printing it to the console:

```
def timeit(description: String)(block: => Unit) : Unit = {
  val start = System.currentTimeMillis
  block
  val duration System.currentTimeMillis - start
  println(description + " took " + duration + "ms")
}
```

This is another trick, multiple parameter blocks.  It allows you to use parentheses for the first block, and braces for the second:

```
timeit("setup") {
  do stuff here
  more stuff
  do other stuff
}
// will print "setup took XXXms"
```

Of course, there's a million other variants you can make on this pattern, with varying degrees of sophistication/complexity, but it should be enough to get you started...

Comment: I have a heavy project and wanted to introduce some scala code as a learning experience.

Comment: But, not sure how to call this from java.

Comment: while( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null ){
       if( line.length() < 140 ) continue;      
       addDoc(w, line);
       if( ++N % 100000 == 0)
        TimeUtil.timeit("batch ", ""+ N/1000 );
        
      }

Comment: Ah, I think I will have to define Function0<Long> in java and use it. But, not very pretty.

Comment: Oh no, this is pure Scala code - I wouldn't use it if Java interop was a requirement.  That's probably the sort of thing worth mentioning in your original question!

Comment: @smartnut007 Defining a `Function0<Long>` isn't all that different from defining a `Runnable`, a `Comparator`, or any other of the one-method classes from Java, is it?

Comment: @Kevin it was a rhetorical question... ;-)